# Save the data into a database and return another value from database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want the text (Name of a person) entered in an input field to be saved on mysql database in the column name with a unique id which is a number( auto increment)

After saving the text into the database i want to get the automatically generated id from the database and append it to the url. And want the user to be forwarded to that url

For eg:

- User enters John
- Save john to db with a unique id
- Get the unique id of john
- Append the id to url ( http://example.com?id=1234)
- Forward the user to the url http://example.com?id=1234
- Print the name to the page http://example.com?id=1234

Comment: ok, nice to know you want to do that.  What is stopping you from doing it?  `INSERT INTO ...`, then `SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = John`, then `$url = .... $id`, then use headers Location to sent the user to the other page.  Have fun, if you get stuck post again with a specific question.

Comment: I'm getting an error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"sql205.uhost.ml"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/vol11_4/uhost.ml/mhusl_20847311/gamie.ml/htdocs/register.php on line 2

Answer (score -1):

U can use the normal php code to insert the data to mysql
ex:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="login";
    //connection
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);
    //fetch from form
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['usernam']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $myemail=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);      
    $sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO su values('$myusername','$mypassword','$myemail',0)");

    }
?>
```

This inserts the data into mysql and the sql design needs to be done in such a way that it has an extra column to keep the generated ID

Once the data is entered fetch the details from this column append that to the URL and it will automatically redirect to the specified page with ur id

Example to fetch data from mysql using php:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts where username='$myusername' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Now u can use $row['tablename'] to fetch the value from the database

Comment: Tried it but it saves 0 to the column name!

Comment: I don't want Password e-mail etc, I'm just storing the name of the visitor in database and giving them a unique id which is an int with auto increment

Comment: This is just an example, so modify it to according to ur needs, if u cant do so just give the database name and tablename i will modify the code accordingly

Comment: Db name mhusl_20847311_user and table name people. I modified it as per my needs but it's saving 0 to the row name!